# Vulkan - strange mapping of float shader color values to uchar values in a read buffer

Tags: colors, shader, vulkan

I knew that a range of float color value in a shader [0..1] is mapped into range of [0..255] in UCHAR buffer.

According to this, I was expecting for steps of size of 1/255 in shader color values for each change in UCHAR buffer.

But the results were surprisingly different. Here is for the first two steps:

Red float value in Shader   ->     UCHAR value in a read Buffer

0.000000 -> 0

0.002197 -> 0

0.002198 -> 1

0.006102 -> 1

0.006105 -> 2

The first two steps are around 0.002197 and 0.006102 which are different than the expected steps: 0.00392 and 0.00784.

So what is the mapping formula ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Unsigned integer normalization](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/chap2.html#fundamentals-fixedconv) is based on the formula `f = i/INT_MAX`, where `f` is the floating point value (after clamping to [0, 1]), `i` is the integer value, and `INT_MAX` is the maximum integer value for the integer's bitdepth (255) in this case.

So if you have a float, and want the unsigned, normalized integer value of it, you use `i = f * INT_MAX`. Of course... integers do not have the same precision as floats. So if the result of `f * INT_MAX` is 0.5, what is the integer value of that? It could be 0, or it could be 1, depending on how things are rounded.

Implementations are permitted to round integer values in any way they prefer. They are encouraged to use nearest rounding (the post-conversion 0.49 would become 0, and 0.5 would become 1), but that is *not a requirement*. The only requirements are that it must pick one of the two nearest values (it can't turn 0.5 into 3) and that the exact floating-point values of 0.0 and 1.0 (which includes any values clamped to them) must be exactly represented as integer 0 and `INT_MAX`.

---

If you have an explicit *need* to have direct rounding, you can always do the normalization yourself. In fact, GLSL has specific functions to help you. The following assumes that you are trying to write to a texture with the Vulkan format `R8G8B8A8_UNORM`, and we're assuming you're writing to a storage image, not via outputs from the fragment shader (you can do that too, but you lose blending).

So, step 1 is to change your `layout` format to be `r32ui`. That is, you are now writing an unsigned 32-bit value, rather than 4 unsigned 8-bit normalized values. That's perfectly valid.

Step 2 is to employ the [`packUNorm4x8` function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/packUnorm.xhtml). This function does float-to-integer normalization, but the specification *explicitly* performs rounding correctly. Use the return value of that function in your `imageStore` function, and you're fine.

If you want to write to a fragment shader output, that's a bit more complex. There, you will need to use a different image view, one that uses the `R32_UINT` format. So you're creating a 32-bit unsigned integer view of a 4x8-bit normalized texture. That has to become a render target, so you're going to have to do subpass surgery. From there, just write the result of `packUNorm4x8`.

Of course, you immediately lose blending and similar operations, since you're writing integers values. And since you had to do that subpass surgery, it's likely that any shader writing to it will need to do this too.

Also, note that in both cases, you will likely need to adjust the order of the components of the value you write. `packUNorm4x8` is explicitly defined to be little endian, whereas (I believe?) `R8G8B8A8` is specified to be in that order, most-significant to least. So you'll probably need to essentially do endian swapping with `packUNorm4x8(value.abgr)`.

Comment: Thanks Nicol. The description strengths the question. It would be expected that
because 0.00196 * 255 = 0.5, then first step will happen for 0.00196. But as I had show, the first step happen in the value 0.002197.  very different value. So something here is not working according to the formula round(f*255)

Comment: @audi02: I said "Implementations are permitted to round integer values **in any way they prefer**." That includes rounding at 0.56 rather than 0.5.

Comment: Why to do such strange rounding while there is existing one just round around 0.5?

Comment: @audi02: Does it matter why it exists? You can't *change* it. You can only recognize that it is possible and accept that there will be a degree of uncertainty in the last digit across platforms.

Comment: The answer to "why" is basically that it's surprisingly expensive in HW to do this "perfectly". For most applications the required properties are sufficient, so the compromise is made to allow higher performance for a given area (cost) and power budget.

Comment: Understand your points, but I suspect as the difference between the expected threshold 0.00196 and the found threshold 0.00219 is an error of  0.0023 which is large relative to the floating points epsilon , and a GPU is built in with floating points arithmetic. It is defined in IEEE - "IEEE Single-Precision Floating Point Format is approximately 0.000000119. Note that if the number x contains 7 digits or less, then x is represented with full accuracy". 
I will do some more checks and be back. Thanks Nicol and Jesse

Comment: @audi02: "*an error of 0.0023 which is large relative to the floating points epsilon*" But it's small relative to the error of 1/255, which is the only error you're promised when you convert from a float to a normalized integer. Remember: when you do two operations, with two error tolerances, you get the *worst* error of the two operations.